# How to use ImageDataGenerator with multi-label masks for multi-class image segmentation?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

In order to do multiclass segmentation the masks need to be one-hot-encoded. For example if I have a 100 images of shape 224x224x3 with 5 different classes I would have a set of masks with shape (100, 224, 224, 5) i.e the last dimension (the channel) refers to the class of the pixel. Take a grayscale masks that contains 6 classes where each pixel has the label 1-6, I can easily convert this to the categorical mask I need using tf.keras.utils.to_categorical.

If I use the ImageDataGenerator provided with keras I know I can create a generator for both images and masks then zip them together for the problem (as code shows below) but where i'm confused is how do I convert the masks into this categorical one-hot-encoded structure whilst using the ImageDataGenerator? The ImageDataGenerator only finds files in directories that are saved as images therefore I can't convert the masks and then save them down as numpy arrays (the one-hot-encoded masks) for the generator to pick up, as images can't have that have more than 4 channels right? Is there somehow of telling the generator to do this conversion? Or does this therefore limit the number of classes I can have in my problem?

One solution is to write my own custom generator with the sequence class which I have done but I'm keen on understanding if this is possible to do with Keras inbuilt ImageDataGenenerator? Could writing my a lambda layer on the network be the solution?

```
mask_categorical = tf.keras.utils.to_categoricl(mask) #converts 224x224 grayscale mask to one-hot encoding version



imgDataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)

maskDataGen = ImageDataGenerator()

imageGenerator =imageDataGen.flow_from_directory("dataset/image/",
                                                class_mode=None, seed=40)

maskGenerator = maskDataGen.flow_from_directory("dataset/mask/",
                                               class_mode=None, seed=40)

trainGenerator = zip(imageGenerator, maskGenerator)
```